# How do I get multiple model values from a single selection using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and need to ask one basic question. I have a select box in which the user can select a country from the country list. Once a country is selected, the value is the country code. I need to change this and update both the country name and country code when selecting any country.

Here is the current code:

```
<select ng-model="model.country_code" ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in countries">
```

My requirement is to set one more value called country_name in model once user selects some value in select box.

**Basically I need to update two model entries on a single selection.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assign the whole object to the `ng-model`, and filter it:

```
<select ng-model="model.country_code" ng-options="c as c.name for c in countries">
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked fine however i did it using a iteration for country object and compared the key since there was an existing logic for it.